# How do I find the records containing a comma-separated value?

Tags: mysql

I've got a field in my database which contains comma-separated integers, for example:

```
"4,6,18,26,29,34"
```

I need to construct an SQL query which will return the record which contains a specific given integer, for example `6`, so my current query is like this:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE CSVField LIKE "%,6,%"
```

I've surrounded the desired value with commas to avoid `6` matching `26` however it's obvious that my current query won't match against the first or last values in the field because the field doesn't start or end with a comma, so in the example above it'll never find `4` or `34`.

How can I write my query so that it'll do what I want?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad/3653574

Comment: `WHERE FIND_IN_SET(6,CSVField)`

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE CSVField LIKE "%,6,%"
                         OR CSVField LIKE "6,%"
                         OR CSVField LIKE "%,6"
```

Hope you table is quite small though.

**UPDATE**

Following Mihai's post, try:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE FIND_IN_SET(CSVField,'6') > 0
```

Comment: Though I like my answer (absolutely clear for the reader), Mihai's suggestion would be best.